# Detect When UITableViewCell is About To Leave The UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to animate a `UITableViewCell` whenever it is about to leave the view. I know that there is a `didEndDisplayingcell` function, but by then, it is too late to animate the cell. Becuase it's gone. I basically want to cell to scale down using...

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    self.cellView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)
}
```

...and whenever it comes back on the screen, scale it back to normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not able to test a proper solution, but as a table view is essentially based upon a scroll view, you should be able to use the content offset of the scroll view and compare it to the height of the table itself, and the position of the cell itself. From these 3 values you should be able to know when the cell is about to be shown or hidden.

Comment: It should be quite easy to implement something like that using a custom CollectionViewFlowLayout and a `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but this might get you there:

```
self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Use this to find whats on the screen.

```
for path in self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows! {
    //check if it's past a point on the screen
    //animate if needed
}
```

Check for these conditions in

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // call the function to check if cells pass a threshold
}
```

The last bit will be setting it up so cells are fully visible on first load, but after that they start off in the state to be animated in.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to approach this would be to check when the cell is finished being displayed via the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
func tableView(UITableView, didEndDisplaying: UITableViewCell, forRowAt: IndexPath)
```

> Tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the table.